# Convert # to #! urls in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

so my problem is simple . I am using Angular js and all my urls are normal # urls but now I want to do SEO and facebook crawling for which I would need to convert to #! urls . Which is ok but the main problem is the urls which we have sent out in emails earlier they are not #! so I want to know is there some way to convert normal # url to #! .

Comment: I *think* you are asking how to change the site to use `#!` and at the same time preserving the previous `#` functionality, essentially handling both simultaneously, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean changing the hashbang prefix? Because that can be done with

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

in a config part of your app

Comment: No actually its like this old url : http://revleg.com/#/search   ,  new_url : http://revleg.com/#!/search .. So now i have added $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!'); to handle hashbang but for old urls like the one mentioned above i am getting error  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$location/ihshprfx? and its not working properly . I saw some solution like if (window.location.hash.indexOf('#/') == 0)
            {
                window.location.hash = '#!' + window.location.hash.slice(1);
            } to run it before angular js code .

Comment: please update your question when you provide more context with code like this; if this answer is deleted, your comment will be removed as well, making it hard to provide a clear answer to the question.